# The repository 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64 Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: linux, docker, nvidia, google-container-registry

I'm trying to use a Google Container Registry public image as a base image for a Docker build.  I'm currently using `gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-gpu.2-8`, but the same issue occurs with `gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-gpu.2-6` and `gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu113`; see [this Google page](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-containers/docs/choosing-container) for reference.

If I just have the following 2 lines in my Dockerfile it crashes on the 2nd line:

```sh
FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-gpu.2-8
RUN apt-get update
```

Here's the error I get:

```
 > [ 2/10] RUN apt-get update:
#5 0.597 Get:1 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-focal InRelease [5386 B]
#5 0.629 Ign:2 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
#5 0.647 Get:3 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease [6751 B]
#5 0.669 Ign:4 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
#5 0.681 Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
#5 0.695 Get:6 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release [696 B]
#5 0.713 Get:7 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-fast-socket InRelease [5405 B]
#5 0.735 Err:8 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release
#5 0.735   404  Not Found [IP: 152.195.19.142 443]
#5 0.758 Get:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release.gpg [836 B]
#5 0.779 Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
#5 0.799 Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
#5 0.898 Get:12 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk/main amd64 Packages [239 kB]
#5 1.171 Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
#5 1.282 Get:14 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages [629 kB]
#5 1.513 Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [30.3 kB]
#5 1.622 Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2124 kB]
#5 1.852 Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1708 kB]
#5 2.734 Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [1086 kB]
#5 3.175 Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [863 kB]
#5 15.67 Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1149 kB]
#5 17.75 Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1160 kB]
#5 19.52 Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [26.0 kB]
#5 19.62 Reading package lists...
#5 20.71 E: The repository 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

I've tried some ideas found [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-with-cuda-repository-on-ubuntu-20-04/188023), but wasn't able to get any of them to work.

It looks like the site developer.download.nvidia.com is currently down.  Will this work when it comes back up, or did nvidia move the location of their downloads?

How can I change my Dockerfile so I can `RUN apt-get update` after starting `from` one of the Google GPU base images?

Comment: It may have something to do with the Ubuntu distribution you are using is outdated. Also found a [GitHub article](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-infrastructure/issues/1399) with a similar error caused by the distribution being broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site developer.download.nvidia.com must have been down.  Trying again this morning works.